# Is it possible to make a pivot table in Google Spreadsheets using data from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets-api

Is it Is it possible to make a pivot table in Google Spreadsheets using data from Google Analytics?

Example:

**Row**: ga:channelGrouping
**Column**: ga:month
**Metric**: ga:sessions

Answer (score 0):

you may use Google Analytics Sheets Add-on to fetch data from Analytics and then build a pivot table over it. Check it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Also you may use Apps script available in sheets to make an API request to Analytics and get the pivoted data directly from Analytics. Here is an example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#pivots

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Here are the following requirements and steps you must follow to [create a pivot table in Google Spreadsheets using data from Google Analytics](https://trevorfox.com/2016/01/google-analytics-to-google-spreadsheets-from-data-to-insights/).

> - Google Spreadsheets Google Analytics Add-On already plugged in
> - Basic familiarity with Regular Expressions aka. RegEx (helpful but not necessary)
> - Basic familiarity with Pivot Tables in Google Spreadsheets
> - Blog URLs with dates as subdirectories eg “/2015/08” (or collect post date as Custom Dimension)

Here are also the filter operators you can use:

> - `ga:medium==organic;`  Only organic traffic ( == means equals)
> - `ga:landingPagePath=@20;`  Only landing page URLs that contain 20  (@= means contains)
> - `ga:landingPagePath!@?`    Only landing page URLs that do not contain a query string because that’s mostly garbage. (!@ means does not
>     contain)

For more information, you can visit the following links:

- [How to use pivot table in spreadsheet](https://zapier.com/blog/google-sheets-pivot-table/)
- [Exploring Google Analytics Pivot Tables](https://zapier.com/blog/google-sheets-pivot-table/)
- [Pivot Google Analytics Data to Create User-Facing Views using Excel](https://www.blockspring.com/tutorials/excel-aggregate-pivot-ga-data)